# AngularJS: Directive restrict : 'E' prevents element click() event being called in Jasmine unit test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine

Here are a couple of directives, and unit tests.

Here is the first directive:

```
directive('myTestDirective', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on("click", function(e) {
            scope.clicked = true;
            console.log("clicked");
        }
    }
});
```

And the unit test:

```
describe('my test directive', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        .....
        inject($compile, $rootScope) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            html = '<div my-test-directive></div>';
            elem = angular.element(html);
            compiled = $compile(elem);
            compiled(scope);
            scope.$digest();
        }
    });
    it('should set clicked to true when click() is called', function() {
        elem[0].click();
        expect(scope.clicked).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

When the above unit test is run, the test passes and `clicked` is logged to the console.

However, consider this directive with `restrict: E` added:

```
directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.on("click", function(e) {
            scope.clicked = true;
            console.log("clicked");
        }
    }
});
```

And the unit test:

```
describe('my directive', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        .....
        inject($compile, $rootScope) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            html = '<my-directive></my-directive>';
            elem = angular.element(html);
            compiled = $compile(elem);
            compiled(scope);
            scope.$digest();
        }
    });
    it('should set clicked to true when click() is called', function() {
        elem[0].click();
        expect(scope.clicked).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

This test fails. `clicked` is not logged to the console. From debugging I can see that the function bound the `click()` binding for the directive is not being executed.

How can I continue to use `restrict : 'E'`, while still retaining the ability to simulate clicks in unit tests?

Update: I have it working, thanks to Michal's plunkr.

I changed the inject() function to be:

```
inject(function($compile, $rootScope, $document) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    html = '<my-test-directive-element></my-test-directive-element>';
    elem = angular.element(html);
    $compile(elem)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
});
```

After this, both clicking using restrict attribute and restrict element work.

Plukr is here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/fgcKrYUEyCJAyqc4jj7P

Comment: Do you see different behaviour if you add a simple `template = '<div></div>`?

Comment: try to change inject method content to: 
`scope = $rootScope.$new();
html = '<my-directive></my-directive>';
compiled = $compile(html)(scope);
scope.$digest();`

Comment: I've created [a Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VmQ3AyHxVxkU1ABt3WLS?p=preview) with very similar directives and tests to your example. Both tests are passing fine with the simulated clicks. Can you post a Plunkr showing your tests failing?

Comment: I tried both suggestions from David and tschiela and still had the same result.

Comment: The linked plunkr in the question shows correct behavior at present.

Answer (score 2):

Using jqLite on('click') is not very Angular-ish and I don't think it would be processed by Angular digest cycle (thus whatever you would add to your scope within that callback wouldn't be rendered in your DOM unless you do it manually). You should prefer using the built-in ng-click directive within yours, so the html code becomes:

```
<my-directive ng-click="onClick()"></my-directive>
```

and your directive:

```
directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.onClick = function() {
        scope.clicked = true;
        console.log("clicked");
      }
    }
  }
});
```